# Factor affecting acidity:Hybridization

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have problem here
So I had learn that the percent of s-character of hybrid orbital will affect the bond strength. The higher percentage of s-character,the stronger the bond.For example the strength C-H in ethane(sp3,25%) is the weakest followed by in ethene(sp2,33%) and strongest in acetylene(sp,50%)

The percentage of s-character of the hybrid orbital also affect the acidity.The higher the percentage of s-character,the stronger the acidity. The reason here is that the conjugated base formed is more stable as the electron is in lower energy and pulled nearer to the nucleus of the atom.For example, acidity hydrogen ion in C-H for compound ethane is weakest followed by ethene and acetylene being the most acidic.

But isn't the C-H bond strength in the acetylene is  the strongest.So it should be hard for acetylene to loss it hydrogen. So why isn't the acetylene being the least acidic? Can someone explain to me?

Comment: The carbon in ethyne is very much electrophilic compared to ethane/ethene.

Comment: Ya, I know about this,but as I stated in the last paragraph, the strength C-H in ethyne is the strongest among the three. So, isn't the H+ is harder to release from C-H in ethyne. Or this effect is not strong and can be ignored?

Comment: Take the hydrogen halide as example.The bond length of H-A where A is halogen(Cl,Br and I) increase down the group,hence the H-A bond strength decrease down the group and so the acidity of hydrogen hallide increase down the group.

Comment: Yes, it's stronger, but it's means that energy of *homo*lytic cleavage is higher, not heterolytic - that's what happens in acid base reactions.

Comment: Ok after seeing the other post ans, I get it now. Tqvm